# How to add subview on the frame of popover not in popover?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, copy, parent-child

I am new to xcode, and i am trying to add some buttons as subview of self.view but i want to add these subviews of buttons within the frame of POPOVER not in popover.. is that any way to make it possible that i can add the buttons on popover frame?

Comment: try with setting frame of the buttons after you set frame of the popover in the code or if you are using IB to design then put your buttons after popover. Try if that works for you.

Comment: not workin, actually i tried this before it gets the value of popovers heght and width suppose which are 140, 140 and add subview in self.view at 140 140 x y cordinate, actually i need button to appear on popover

Comment: set the frame of the button with respect to superview of popover & add button to the superview of popover..also bring button to front...

Answer (score 0):

Use UINavigationViewController as popovers content.
And then use navigationItem and toolbarItems in your's viewDidLoad.